# Fonts not loading from CDN servers

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, fonts, cdn

I am using cdn servers for better performance for my application for this i moved the font files also to cdn server that used by CSS which is also present in CDN.
But when i browse the page the font files are not loading and showing ...

Font from origin 'https://onesitip.yworld.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://onesit.yworld.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I have also added CORS configuration to cdn server main Config but still issue is same.

Comment: 401 is the unauthorized status code, so depending on your CDN you probably need to authorize your domain to access the fonts. Are you able to pull other assets from the CDN?

Comment: Yes , i am able to pull other resource like Images and css from cdn only issue with the Font files...
Also when i open the page in IE the *.eot fonts are loading ...But in chrome n firefox the *.woff & *.ttf fonts are giving above error

Comment: Ok it looks like your website is behind an SSL certificate which means that you will need to make sure the link to your fonts is also being requested over https. It looks like the status code is HTTP. As a note you can remove the http or https from a resource link and it will load over whichever your website is on. `://your/resource/link/here`

Comment: No use :( Also tried different cors setting at server side

Comment: Can you provide any information regarding the requst/repsonse from the browser

Comment: Actually we figure out issue that the CORS tag is removed by the webseal server ..Now we are expecting the setting or changes we need in webseal so that it wont remove the CORS tag

Comment: for *.ttf and the images response it wont remove that CORS header and only for .woff & .ttf files its removing the cors heade .so please let me know the solution